# Attribute table conversion date format

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, date, format

I want to change the date format with different date formats in the attribute table to the one format which is fitting for the Time manager. Does it work with the Field Calculator?

For example 12.August 2020 and I want to have 2020-08-12. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: a couple more tags wouldn't hurt either

Comment: Its QGIS 3.4...

Comment: I want to choose some other but it doesnt work :/ sorry

Comment: Take a look at format_date() expression ;)

Answer (score 1):

To convert your example string (which I assume is not actually a date value):

```
to_date('12.August 2020', 'd.MMMM yyyy')
```

This will give a datetime value.

To convert it directly to the new format:

```
format_date(to_date('12.August 2020', 'd.MMMM yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Producing `2020-08-12`

You will need to substitute your field name for '12.August 2020' for this to work, i.e.:

```
format_date(to_date("myDate", 'd.MMMM yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString) for information on date formats and string conversion, or look at the help in the field calculator for `format_date()`.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work with this string...is something wrong with the command?

Comment: Can you help me with that string please?

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste exactly what I wrote here? I tested this in QGIS 3.14 and 3.10; if you're on 3.4 perhaps there is some functionality missing.

Comment: Ive try it with 3.4...thats why its not working...

Comment: @andrea Any reason you can't use the recent long-term-support version?