# Choosing correct datetime format

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, date, format

I want to change my date (string) to a date format `%Y-%m-%d` for the time manager. I already try with the Field Calculator. But it is not working. What should i write in the expression. And should I create a new field?

[image]

Comment: Did you pay attention to a function [`format_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#format-date), that *"formats a date type or string into a custom string format"*, i.e. `yyyy-M-dd`? Also you may be interested in other two functions [`to_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-datetime) and [`to_datetime()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-datetime).

Comment: Sorry for being a bit annoying, but how exactly this question different to your previous one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374761/attribute-table-conversion-date-format?

Answer (score 3):

You should calculate a new field with field calculator. Notice the difference between capital and small characters! Here is an expression which should work. It first converts the content of your start_date field to a date type and then reformats it:

```
format_date(to_date("start_date",'dd.MM.yyyy'), 'yyyy-M-d')
```